# how to size the silverlight object to available space

Tags: jquery, css, silverlight

I'm trying to follow Bob Andrews css styling for a [sticky footer](http://www.tightcss.com/layouts/stickyfooter.htm), what I'm trying to do is place the silverlight control (the `<object>` tag) in the main content area with it's size filling all the available space.  If you take a look at Bob's demo page, what I'm after is the silverlight control occupying all the yellow part.

What I suspect I'll need to do is set the hight of the object in jquery/javascript as the browser resizes, but at that point I'm stumped.  Is it possible to do this without jquery, or if not then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using pure CSS, I think you cannot do that.

As a DOM element, I think the following works using jQuery.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#yourobjectid').height($(window).height() - hoffset );
    $('#yourobjectid').width($(window).width() - woffset );
});
```